# Could not get unknown property 'FLIPPER_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, visual-studio-code

This is the error I am getting while I'm trying to get an app to debug on the android emulator from android studio on visual studio code :

> Could not get unknown property 'FLIPPER_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

What went wrong was:

> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>   Could not get unknown property 'FLIPPER_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Where? :

> Build file 'C:\Users\dmdpl\OneDrive\Desktop\citas3\android\app\build.gradle' line: 270

This is what is along the line 270 on app.build.gradle:

```
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check latest flipper version [here](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native/#using-the-latest-flipper-sdk) and then update
`android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
......
        FLIPPER_VERSION="0.240.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"
```

Comment: Adding it to the `gradle.properties` file also fixes the issue.
`FLIPPER_VERSION="<version>"`

Answer (score 1):

`${FLIPPER_VERSION}` is meant to act as a placeholder for whatever the latest version is of the library

Replace

```
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
```

with

```
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.156.0")
```

Comment: There are several statements with the "${FLIPPER_VERSION}" so i guess i should go ahead an put the version on them too.

Answer (score 1):

ensure you have your `gradle.properties` file in your `android/` folder, if that file exists you should already see the version of `FLIPPER` defined in there already.

I had this error while I was trying to move my project to another computer, the `gradle.properties` file was not included, so I had to copy it manually to the new computer.

Then, all I needed to do, was to open the app on my Android studio and ran: `Sync project with gradle files`.